# strange browser html refresh issue

Tags: html, caching, browser

I updated my nameservers and index.html. ubnutu Opera browser shows the changes fine. But ubuntu firefox and chrome still have the previous html. I have refreshed, cleared the cache, installed web developer tools add on, cleared again, installed various other cache clear tools. But 12 hours later it is still on the old html page. On firefox via a proxy webpage I can see the new page fine. But type in the url normally and its still on the old page. So annoying when I know my server has the new index page o.k. Can I add something to the top of the index.html to make sure the page is refreshed from new each and every time any browser tries to load it?  Thanks for help : )

Comment: Have you tried flushing your DNS?

Comment: i googled about and tried this  sudo apt-get install nscd but this did not change anything.  I am using the most basic html page. should i have something in the header to enforce no cache? strange that opera works but not firefox and chrome:?

Comment: firefox/chrome is still showing the parked page from the domain provider no matter how i try to clear cache (but opera is o.k). my new html file is very basic, no jpegs, just a bit of text, but i have a .htaccess file to try and stop any caching. 

my .htaccess   

<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|xml|txt|css|js)$">
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>

Comment: It just takes around 48hrs for the cache to clear on the virgin super hub. one can use a proxy website to view a new domain or Opera browser as that uses a proxy. or go to another router that has not recently viewed the domain.(a coffee shop, friends house) to see it.